# Split String To Array

Tags: java

I've been trying to split an string by a character and store each split value inside an array. 
In C# it can be done by calling the .ToArray() method after the Split() but such method apparently doesn't exits in Java. So I've been trying to do this like this (rs is a string list with elements separated by #) :

```
    String t[] = new String[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < rs.size(); i++) {
        t = null;
        t = rs.get(i).split("#");
    }
```

But the whole split line is passed to an index of the array like:

```
String x = "Hello#World"  -> t[0] = "Hello World" (The string is split in one line, so the array will have only one index of 0)
```

My question is that how can store each spit element in an index of the array like :

```
t[0] = "Hello"
t[1] = "World"
```

Comment: That can't be happening. Can you show where are you using the array? And did you notice that you are overwriting the same array reference to a new array on each loop?

Comment: @RohitJain, Yes, that is exactly what I've been trying to do, I want to do other thing later inside the loop

Comment: Which part of my comment are you referring to by *"that is"*?

Comment: @RohitJain: overwriting the array I mean

Comment: Please show some more code. The way you are doing the *other thing*. The split is fine.

Comment: @RohitJain: the other parts would be inappropriate as for example simply printing the array in another loop.

Comment: Your question currently is not very clear. It is rather a classic case of [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/196975). You should modify your question. The output you are telling you get for that code, can never be like that. Splitting `"Hello#World"` on `#` will never return a single element array with `"Hello World"`. So, try to add the relevant part of the code, else we can't help you.

Comment: The last part of my question is asking on how to do this, I know that my code doesn't doesn't work, it's only there to show what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your trying to loop through a list, split them then add the arrays together? What your defining as the problem with the .split method is exactly what the split method does.

```
    ArrayList<String> rs = new ArrayList<>();
    rs.add("Hello#World");
    rs.add("Foo#Bar#Beckom");

    String [] t = new String[0];
    for(int i=0;i<rs.size();i++) {
        String [] newT = rs.get(i).split("#");
        String [] result = new String[newT.length+t.length];
        System.arraycopy(t, 0, result, 0,  t.length);
        System.arraycopy(newT, 0, result, t.length, newT.length);
        t = result;
    }

    for(int i=0;i<t.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(t[i]);
    }
```

Works just find output is:

```
Hello
World
Foo
Bar
Beckom
```

Comment: Did you check your rs array and make sure that the inputs your putting into this loop match what you would expect to see? My guess is your getting "Hello\tWorld" because that is one of the strings not "Hello#World"

Comment: This is a very good point ns47731, never came to my mind. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, I didn't come to my mind that the list may have a problem, and yes it does.

Comment: My rule of debugging, check your input before you check our output

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
String string = "Hello#World"
String[] parts = string.split("#");
String part1 = parts[0]; // Hello
String part2 = parts[1]; // World
```

It is always good to test beforehand if the string contains a #(in this case), just use [**String#contains()**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29).

```
if (string.contains("#")) {
    // Split it.
} else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(message);
}
```

Comment: The string is split in one line so the array has only one index which is 0.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String hw = "Hello#World";

    String[] splitHW = hw.split("#");

    for(String s: splitHW){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
}
```

This produced following output for me:

```
Hello
World
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you using a loop when the problem is already solved in java..
try this

```
String x = "Hello#World";
String[] array = x.split("#", -1);

System.out.println(array[0]+" "+array[1]);
```

Comment: `#` is not special character in regex so you don't need to escape it using \\ or quote.